Give an example of an abelian group in which the only element of finite order is the identity but it is not a free abelian group.
I am trying to find an example of an abelian group in which the only element of finite order is the identity but it is not a free abelian group. I know that if we add an extra condition that the group is finitely generated, then the group must be a free abelian group. So, I tried to find an abelian group which is not finitely generated.
I considered $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$. It is abelian alright, but for some reason it should fail to have a basis (I think). However, I am unable to find such a reason.
Thank you for your kind help.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Thanks, I edited the question.

What about this post?

Thank you @Dietrich. But I still don't see why $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ should fail to have a basis. A basis can have infinitely many elements, and by finite linear combinations of these infinitely many elements we may construct all rational numbers. And it is still possible this basis is linearly independent (at least I do not see why it should not be).

See Baer-Specker group for $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$.

What about the additive group of all polynomials?

Thank you both. But the part I am unable to do is showing that these suggested groups really fail to have a basis. I couldn't prove any of them should not have a basis. The proof for the group I had in mind, Baer-Specker group, is probably quite hard considering it is only proven in 1937. However, if there is a group with an easier proof, please let me know.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_abelian_group

See this duplicate for $(\Bbb Q,+)$.

See this duplicate, why $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bbb Z$ is not free-abelian.

This solved my problem. Thank you @Dietrich.
